# How to show the field label name in color in Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, custom-object

I have a Visualforce page created on a custom object. This page is related to a list button as"edit all". When user clicks on this button for editing the VF page, it should show the editing field label names in red color. Any suggestion plz.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you share some code you've started to do to help us know what specific problem you need to have solved?

Comment: @Peter@Jenny B:Thanks for you reply.But im using the <apex:column>tag with field names.

Comment: @nikkey updated my answer with one way you could do it using facets and a similar approach to label.

Comment: @Jenney :using facets it didnot work on my sceanrio

Comment: @nikkey, another example added for columns in EDIT2

Answer (score 2):

There are several different ways you can do this, take a look at the help docs [here](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_styling_custom.htm).

> For HTML tags , you can define inline CSS code just like in a regular
>   HTML page:
>
> ```
> <apex:page>
>     <style type="text/css">
>         p { font-weight: bold; }
>     </style>
>
>     <p>This is some strong text!</p>
> </apex:page>
> ```

The above example should work if you wanted to change all of your labels to red, something like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
    label { color: red; }
</style>
```

> The following example shows how to reference a stylesheet that is
>   defined as a static resource. First, create a stylesheet like the one
>   below and upload it as a static resource named customCSS:
>
> ```
> h1 { color: #f00; }
> p { background-color: #eec; }
> newLink { color: #f60; font-weight: bold; }
> ```
>
> Next, create a page that refers to this static resource:
>
> ```
>     <apex:page showHeader="false">
>         <apex:stylesheet value="{!$Resource.customCSS}" />
>         <h1>Testing Custom Stylesheets</h1>
>         <p>This text could go on forever...<br/><br/>
>            But it won't!</p>
>
>         <apex:outputLink value="http://www.salesforce.com" styleClass="newLink">
>             Click here to switch to www.salesforce.com
>         </apex:outputLink>
>     </apex:page>
> ```
>
> Tip
>
> To shrink the size of your page, you can prevent the standard
>   Salesforce stylesheets from loading by setting the standardStylesheets
>   attribute on the  component to false:
>
> ```
>     <apex:page standardStylesheets="false">
>         <!-- page content here -->
>     </apex:page>
> ```
>
> Note that if you don’t load these style sheets, components that
>   require Salesforce CSS might not display correctly, and their styling
>   may change between releases.
>
> All Visualforce components that produce HTML have pass-through style
>   and styleClass attributes. They allow you to use your own styles and
>   style classes to control the look and feel of any HTML tag. For
>   example, the following code sets the class of the 
>   and applies a style:
>
> ```
>     <apex:page>
>             <style type="text/css">
>                 .italicText { font-style: italic; }
>             </style>
>             <apex:outputText styleClass="italicText" value="This is kind of fancy."/>
>         </apex:page>
> ```

The above here would work if you were using the `<apex:outputLabel>` tag and could use the styleClass="redText", something like:

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .redText { color: red; }
    </style>
```

EDIT2: Similar to the above example for columns you could also use headerClass to modify the style:

```
<style>
    .headerRow .tableTitle {
        color: red !important; 
    }
</style>
<apex:column value="{!acct.Name}" headerClass="tableTitle"/>
```

Another way that I've seen it done is to create the style and just put the tags in the labels themselves, something like:

```
<style type="text/css">
    redText { color: red; }
</style>  
<apex:inputField value="{!Account.Name}" label="<redText>Acct Name</redText>"/>
```

EDIT: This also works with headers in combination with facets like this:

```
<apex:facet name="header"><redText>Acct Name</redText></apex:facet>
```

> If you want to apply a style using a DOM ID, you must use CSS
>   attribute selectors for the style definition. Attribute selectors rely
>   on the definition of an attribute, rather than an HTML tag, to apply a
>   CSS style. You can set the id value on any Visualforce component;
>   however, that id is sometimes preprended with the id of parent
>   components. For instance, the id of the following code is j_id0:myId:
>
> ```
>     <apex:page>
>         <apex:outputText id="myId" value="This is less fancy."/>
>     </apex:page>
> ```
>
> Your CSS should take this into consideration by using an attribute
>   selector:
>
> ```
>     <apex:page>
>         <style type="text/css">
>             [id*=myId] { font-weight: bold; }
>         </style>
>         <apex:outputText id="myId" value="This is way fancy !"/>
>     </apex:page>
> ```
>
> If you intend to use images in your stylesheet, zip the images with
>   the CSS file and upload it as a single static resource. For example,
>   if your CSS file has a line like the following:
>
> ```
> body { background-image: url("images/dots.gif") }
> ```
>
> Add the entire images directory and the parent CSS file into a single
>   zip file. For example, if the zip file resource name is myStyles,
>   refer to it like this:
>
> ```
> <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.myStyles, 'styles.css')}"/>
> ```
>
> Warning
>
> If a stylesheet has an empty string in a url value, you won’t be able
>   to render that page as a PDF. For example, the style rule body {
>   background-image: url(""); } will prevent any page that includes it
>   from being rendered as a PDF.